# Renaming a directory using .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found a lot of questions regarding mod rewrite on here, but haven't been able to figure out my simple problem.

I have a Wordpress blog that structures the URLs as such:
http://website.com/portfolio/name-of-page

I would like to simply change "portfolio" to another word, "books", so that the URL would read:
http://website.com/books/name-of-page

Is this possible to do via .htaccess mod rewrite? And if so, what are the rules and conditions that are needed?

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies!

Comment: This is probably something you'll need to do in wordpress

Comment: I've been told to edit the .htaccess file, as the names of the folder "portfolio" are set from a plugin.

Comment: Rename folder and change all path from "http://website.com/portfolio/name-of-page" with "http://website.com/books/name-of-page" using sql query..